# Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

So I'm working on a site and I was wondering if it's possible to, purely using HTML5, CSS3 (and JavaScript if needed), make a div with a curved bottom, so it will look practically like this:

[image]

Or can this only be done using a background image?

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: only with a background image, unless you start looking into using canvas

Comment: And should you happen to look into any canvas plugins, [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) is a really nice one.

Comment: check this for the opposite curve: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091451/8620333

Answer (score 51, accepted):

CSS:

```
div{
    background-color:black;
    width:500px;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
}
```

see is this ok for you

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, didn't know i could use percents for radius, thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, could it be possible to make it curve less / is less convex in the corners?

Comment: well, currently the corners are too round imho, can i make the corners sharp.. so it practically looks like if you're taking just the bottom out of a circle instead of half a circle.. don't really know how to explain this -- currently it looks a bit like a streched-out-half-circle

Comment: i dont think that much sharpness can be brought there

Comment: try some changes in the percentage values given, and see if you could get what you are expecting

Answer (score 118):

There are different approaches that can be adopted to create this shape. Below is a detailed description of possibilities:

### SVG Based Approaches:

`SVG` is the recommended way to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale-ability. Below are a couple of possible ways:

**1- Using Path Element:**

We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create this shape and fill it with some solid color, gradient or a pattern.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Below is the necessary code to create this shape:

```
<path d="M 0,0
         L 0,40
         Q 250,80 500,40
         L 500,0
         Z" />
```

Below is a brief description of `path` commands used in above code:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `L` command is used to draw straight lines.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `Z` command is used to close the current path.

*Output Image:*

[image: Div element with curved bottom]

*Working Demo:*

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="80" viewBox="0 0 500 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0,0 L0,40 Q250,80 500,40 L500,0 Z" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

---

**2- Clipping:**

Clipping means removing or hiding some parts of an element.

In this approach, we define a clipping region by using SVG's `clipPath` element and apply this to a rectangular element. Any area that is outside the clipping region will be hidden.

Below is the necessary code:

```
<defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
        <path d="M0,0 L0,40 Q250,80 500,40 L500,0 Z" />
    </clipPath>
</defs>
<rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="80" fill="#000" clip-path="url(#shape)" />
```

Below is brief description of the elements used in above code:

- `defs` element is used to define element / objects for later use in SVG document.
- `clipPath` element is used to define a clipping region.
- `rect` element is used to create rectangles.
- `clip-path` attribute is used to link the clipping path created earlier.

*Working Demo:*

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="80" viewBox="0 0 500 80" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="shape">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,40 Q250,80 500,40 L500,0 Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="80" fill="#000" clip-path="url(#shape)" />
</svg>
```

---

### CSS Based Approaches:

**1- Using Pseudo Element:**

We can use `::before` or `::after` pseudo element to create this shape. Steps to create this are given below:

- Create a layer with `::before` OR `::after` pseudo element having width and height more than its parent.
- Add `border-radius` to create the rounded shape.
- Add `overflow: hidden` on parent to hide the unnecessary part.

*Required HTML:*

All we need is a single `div` element possibly having some class like `shape`:

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

*Working Demo:*

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
}

.shape::before {
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  right: -200px;
  left: -200px;
  top: -200px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

**2- Radial Gradient:**

In this approach we will use CSS3's `radial-gradient()` function to draw this shape on the element as a background. However, this approach doesn't produce very sharp image and it might have some jagged corners.

*Required HTML:*

Only single `div` element with some class will be required i.e.

```
<div class="shape"></div>
```

*Necessary CSS:*

```
.shape {
  background-image: radial-gradient(120% 120px at 50% -30px, #000 75%, transparent 75%);
}
```

*Working Demo:*

```css
.shape {
  background: radial-gradient(120% 120px at 50% -30px, #000 75%, transparent 75%) no-repeat;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

### JavaScript Based Approaches:

Although not required in this case but for the sake of completeness, I'm adding this approach as well. This can be useful in some cases as well:

**HTML5 Canvas:**

We can draw this shape on HTML5 Canvas element using path functions:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(0, 40);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(311, 80, 622, 40);
ctx.lineTo(622, 0);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="622" height="80"></canvas>
```

Below is a brief description of the methods used in above code:

- `beginPath()` is used to create a new path. Once a new path is created, future drawing commands are directed into the path.
- `moveTo(x, y)` moves the pen to the coordinates specified by `x` and `y`.
- `lineTo(x, y)` draws a straight line from the current pen position to the point specified by `x` and `y`.
- `quadraticCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, x, y)` draws a curve from current pen position to the point specified by `x` and `y` using control point specified by `cp1x` and `cp1y`.
- `fill()` fills the current path using non-zero or even-odd winding rule.

---

**Useful Resources:**

- Radial Gradient: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-images-20110217/#radial-gradients), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)
- SVG: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)
- HTML5 Canvas: [Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

Comment: Agreed, this answer makes me wish I could upvote more than once

Answer (score 24):

This is what you want:

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Unlike the accepted answer, this works even when the height of the div is increased.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this in CSS - basically make your div wider than the page to fix the too-rounded edges, then left-positioned to compensate, with bottom border radius using both x & y values, and negative bottom margin to compensate for the gap:

```
.round-bottom { 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 200px; // across half & up 200px at left edge
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 200px; // across half & up 200px at right edge
  width: 160%; overflow: hidden; // make larger, hide side bits
  margin-bottom: -50px; // apply negative margin to compensate for bottom gap
  position: relative; left:-30%; // re-position whole element so extra is on each side (you may need to add display:block;)
}
```

```css
.round-bottom { 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 150px !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 150px !important;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 160%; 
  margin-bottom:-50px;
  left:-30%; 
  background-color:#444;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Tropical_Forest_with_Monkeys_A10893.jpg'); background-position: center center;
  background-size: 42% auto;
  height:150px;
}
.container { width: 100%; height: height:100px; padding-bottom:50px; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="round-bottom"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.navbar{
    border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:50% 50% 0 0;
    background:#000;
    min-height:100px;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/JnCGa/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Incase someonce wanted similar but reverse of this ( for my case)

```
<svg
 height="80"
 viewBox="0 0 500 80"
 preserveAspectRatio="none"
 className="w-full"
>
<path d="M0,0 Q250,80 500,0 L500,80 L0,80 Z" fill="black" fill- 
 rule="evenodd" />
</svg>
```

You can set the height to adjust.