# linearly curved header at the bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Sorry for repeating this question similar to SO here: [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom-with-html-css-js-only)

But method there does not fulfill my customization need of header.
But what [i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOBhr.png) is not quite similar to [what i've achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cKWv.png) with the border `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`.

As you can see the images that header i want to achieve is linearly curved throughout the bottom but with what i've achieved is that i'm having more curvy border at the left and right portion of header and curved is not linear throughout the bottom. It becomes straight after short distance. I've tried to increase the %age but it becomes even more curved at edges.

Is there any other way of doing this so that i get linearly curved throughout the bottom?

Here is my code: 
CSS Code:

```
header{     
        background-color: #000;
        border-bottom-left-radius:25%;
        border-bottom-right-radius:25%;
        padding: 10px;
        opacity: 0.35;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1000;
        }
```

Here is the link JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ozqneuha/

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700);

/* --Global CSS-- */

.header-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Header CSS*/

header {
  background-color: #000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.35;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
header .header-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px;
}
header li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
header li a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px'Open Sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header li a:hover,
header li a:active {
  color: #e51937;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2JbjOqY.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Properties</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Parking</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Residents</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pay Online</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /.header-nav -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.header-container -->
</header>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: have you tried `border-radius: 100%` or `50%` ???

Comment: Jsfiddle  link added.

Comment: @vikrantnegi007 Thanks for the Fiddle, although the code needs to be contained in the question itself (just in case the link goes dead). You can create a Stack Snippet with the Fiddle code which will demonstrate the problem in a similar way.

Comment: @Hidden I've added the code in stack snippet as well.

Comment: A radius of 50% should work for you -- See here: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ozqneuha/1/

Comment: Could not get this to look like you want it just be using `border-radius`, but would `clip-path` be an option ? This is as close as i can get [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/bves8gje/). Also added a bit of responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured out out the solution of this problem. I've used pesudo class `:before` for the solution.

```css
/* --Global CSS-- */

.header-container {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
  height: 100%;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Header CSS*/

header {
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
header:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  width: 150%;
  content: '';
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  top: -76px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -25%;
}
header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header .logo {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header .header-nav {
  display: table-cell;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
header li a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px'Open Sans';
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header li a:hover,
header li a:active {
  color: #e51937;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2JbjOqY.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Properties</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Parking</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Residents</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pay Online</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /.header-nav -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.header-container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give `clip-path` a try, but make sure to check browser support.

[**Can I use CSS clip-path property**](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path)

You basically just use an ellipse to clip your header div.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700);

body {
  margin: 0;  
}

/* --Global CSS-- */
.header-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
  text-align: right;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

/* Header CSS*/

header{
  background-color: #000;
  /*
  border-bottom-left-radius:25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:25%;
  */
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0.35;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  min-height: 50px;
  -webkit-clip-path: ellipse(60% 100% at 50% 0%);
  clip-path: ellipse(60% 100% at 50% 0%);

}

header nav ul{
  list-style-type: none; 
}

header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

header .header-nav{
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: right;*/
  padding: 7px;
}

header li{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

header li a{
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px 'Open Sans';  
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
} 

header li a:hover,
header li a:active{
  color: #e51937;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1169px) {
  .header-container {
    width: 840px;    
  }
  header .header-nav{
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
  .header-container {
    width: 100%;    
  }
  header .logo {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header .header-nav{
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">            
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2JbjOqY.png" alt="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Properties</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Residents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pay Online</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div><!-- /.header-nav -->
  </div><!-- /.header-container -->
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this way?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700);

/* --Global CSS-- */

.header-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1170px;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Header CSS*/

header {
  background-color: #000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px 10px 35px;
  opacity: 0.35;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
header nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
header .logo {
  display: inline-block;
}
header .header-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 7px;
}
header li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
header li a {
  color: #fff;
  font: 600 16px'Open Sans';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header li a:hover,
header li a:active {
  color: #e51937;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/2JbjOqY.png" alt="logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="header-nav">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Search</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Map</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Properties</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Parking</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Residents</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pay Online</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /.header-nav -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.header-container -->
</header>
```

Comment: Can you draw and give how it should appear?

Comment: I've already added the image of what i want to achieve in the post. Here it is http://i.imgur.com/iv6AuNf.png

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
    top: -60%;
    background: rgba(121, 121, 121, 0.8);
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d2sL83v9/)

Adjust the `width`, `left` and `top` percentage to your liking :)