# How can I create div with an opposite-curved bottom

Tags: css, wordpress, image, curve

So I found this question: [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom/)

Thanks to it I managed to make a curved bottom of an image, using code below:

```
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 15%;
    overflow: hidden;
```

It looks [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrlUT.jpg):

[image]

(practically). Everything would be nice but... I need the curve to be [totally opposite way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYwm2.png):

[image]

How can I do that with clean CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: -25%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Okay, nice! That's what I needed ;)

Here's my code I used in the end:

`div#headerwrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#headerwrap:after {
  content: "";
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 15%;
  bottom: -25%;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with just one div. Border-radius doesn't work that way. However, you can achieve something like that with multiple elements. Overlay a second div on the first with a curved top, masking part of the upper div. If you like, enclose it all in a container with overflow: hidden; to obscure the bottom part of the overlay div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="curved">
    </div>
    <div class="curved-overlay">
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.curved-overlay{
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0 / 15%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -15%;
}

.curved{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.container{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKjNPa