# HTML, CSS custom overlay

Tags: html, css

I will attach an image with the effect I'm trying to achive using html and css.

[image]

Instead of the black color, I'll have an image, and I want to make an white overlay to give the impression of a round bottom. This could be done using an background image but I'd like to make this using css and keep that option as a last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting 50% to `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` should give you the expected results.

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
```

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```css
div {
    background-color: orange;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, but it's not exactly what I'm trying to achive. As you can see your example is much more round on the edges than it needs to be, see @Hemant 's answer. It think that one is the closest to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JohnDoe see I just wanted to give you an idea on how you can solve what you're trying. Now it's just about playing around with those `50%` values.. I will not try to get the exact shape your looking for, also cause it depends on width/height proportion. Why not accepting Hemants answer if you like that one the most? The one you accepted does not solve your question! It's not better then mine cause it's the same + missing the image and `overflow:hidden;` part which is important to your question! not the bluddy `50%` shape stuff ... what ever

Answer (score 1):

This shape can be achieved by using 2 HTML elements.

We set the rectangular primary element to `overflow: hidden`.

The child element should be shaped as an oval (can be done via `border-radius`), and scaled+translated a bit so that it has only the bottom edge within the main element area.

Please try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aufus62z/).

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, this looks very promising and the closest answer to what I'm trying to achive. I'll try it out !