# Skew in top with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to skew my div with border-radius-left-top and border-radius-left-right but I think that isn't solution. To understand what I'm trying to do, here it's image: [image]

```
border-radius: 50% / 100%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
```

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom

Comment: I have tried, but isn't solution what I'm doing

Comment: May I ask why it didn't work for you? It seems to be exactly the same, but flipped. What is different about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, because in the corner is very curved

Comment: You should just need to modify the radius to make it match what you want then.

Answer (score 0):

Your border-radius has this shape because the circle has different height and width(like in pink-one). For correct shape it should be like square. Height should be equal width. Use pseudo element to do this(the third div):

```css
*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.one {
  background-color: #fcfdfe;
}

.one:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.two {
  margin-top: -70px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  background-color: #edf3f8;
  border-top-left-radius: 200% 240px;
  border-top-right-radius: 200% 240px;
}

.three {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #10538c;
}
.three-border{
  position:absolute;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:70px;
  top:-70px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
.three-border:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 300vw;
  width: 300vw;
  margin: 0 -100vw;
  background-color: #10538c;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="one">1111</div>
<div class="two">2222</div>
<div class="three">
  <div class="three-border"></div>
  3333
</div>
```