# How can create a bottom curve aside bottom-border-radius

Tags: css, curve

I would like to make a rounded div using css, I already used the `bottom-border-radius` but I dont want that, if there is any other way to achieve that please share.

I know this can be achieved by using `bottom-border-radius` but is there any other way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom)

Comment: No its not, I'm looking a another to do asides that...

Comment: Can you show the code that you have, so that we may understand why applying `border-radius` to it is not feasible.

Comment: What does "I don't want that" mean? It's an appropriate CSS property to set the radius of one corner of your div, so if that works: you do want that. But if you're adamant that you don't, please *explain* why you need a different property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will use shorthand `border-radius` property and also individually have to  give values like this

```css
.sample1 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
.sample2 {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample1">
</div>

<div class="sample2">
</div>
```