# Email approved css/html design for curved gradient container with content

Tags: html, css, email

I'm looking for a way to complete the following design:

[image: Result: Container with angular gradient]

The solution I'm loooking for needs to be email-approved, e.g. using tables.

I've tried the solutions from: [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom) without success.

Comment: It is better you use the background images for the curved part.

Comment: simply use an image, the most email-approved way

Comment: I would use an image too. SVG would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you!! Okey, I've tried using a .svg and it does the work. Thanks! A bit tricky to make it responsive — preferring only inline-styling for email compatibility!