# How to make a background with curved bottom and also with a pattern in it?

Tags: html, css

So I have this design where I need to curve the bottom of the section.

The design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSeGY.jpg

I have also gone with this great answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45792490/11054558) where I am able to make a shape like shown in my design and I was able to implement it as well. [image]

You can see that, but the issue here is that it is a shape, I want it as a background. I also want a pattern inside it. This is the link to my development page : http://www.saitec.krenovate.xyz/catalyst/.

Please help!

Comment: This is a landing page, and I have to take care of the speed and responsiveness as well. I think I would be able to achieve that through code only. Else I will have to design for mobile and tablet and then switch background images. Is my assumption wrong? please correct if I am wrong

Comment: from the link you shared you can use an image with the pseudo element approach

Comment: How would I add the pattern inside it? Will the pattern spread seamlessly ?

Comment: simply replace the background color with image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fgvtuL1c/

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle solution, but how can I add elements inside of `.shape` . Right now anything I add is behind the shape.

Comment: add a negative z-index to the pseudo element

Comment: Oh yes, thanks that worked. !!