# Can I create a div with a curved bottom in CSS?

Tags: html, css, border

Is it possible to create a complete curve to the bottom of a div in css? 
The curve should stop at the border of the parent element.

I tried: `border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 50px;`, but it gives a strange end to it.

This is my html (the header should have a curved bottom):

```
<div class="container">
    <header class="home__header">
        <h1 class="title">Gift<span class="home--apos">'</span>it</h1>
        <img src="assets/img/presents.svg" alt="presents" class="home__image">
    </header>
    <main class="home__content">
        <div class="home--container">
            <p>Heb je wel eens een cadeau vergeten kopen?<br> 
                Weet je niet waar je het best kan kopen?<br> 
                Ga dan naar onze Cadeau planner!</p>

            <a class="home__btn" href="form.html">
                plan it!
            </a>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThbLO.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Please run an SO search for similar questions to yours because there are quite a few that may help_ including this one >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
.home__header {
  background-color: teal;
  border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
  width: 250px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/bkiss/pen/NWWeZWO