# HTML, CSS - Large flexible circle for navigation

Tags: html, css

I asked this earlier and was sent: [Can I create a div with a Curved bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom)

But a curved bottom div is not what I want.
I am after a very large circle (not just with a curved bottom but a proper circle)... which is positioned with a negative margin-top and has a flexible width when the browser windows is resized.

[Here's an image of exactly what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltFww.jpg)

[Here's an image of what the layout should look like zoomed out - so you can see the whole circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlpTn.jpg)

Here's what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/etmgho6s/

```
#container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

#nav-bg {
width: 90vw;
height: 90vw;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top: -45vw;
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
}

#title {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Josh

Comment: You have a circle there. It's not just rounded it's a perfect circle.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```css
#container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
display: flex; /* line added */
justify-content: center; /* line added */
}

#nav-bg {
width: 150vw;
height: 90vw;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top: -60vw;
background: red;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
}

#title {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="nav-bg"></div>
  <h1 id="title">Navigation content goes here</h1>

</div>
```