# is there a way to make custom border with no straight lines

Tags: html, css, border, accordion

Is there a way to make borders like in the image I have attached

this is an accordion with heading hover effect
[image: this is an accordion with heading hover effect]

Comment: Perhaps using [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG). [Search around for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040709/can-i-create-a-div-with-a-curved-bottom), and see what might work for you.

Comment: Sure, check out CSS [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image), combined with `clip-path`...

Comment: you can make individual `div` and give them `border-top` or `border-bottom`. For **text** use `margin-left` to align them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>

    <title>(title of document !)</title>

    <style>
       .(write class_name of specific tag you want to add border):hover{font-size:50px;
        transition:0.5s;
        border:1px solid red (#color of border);
        border-radius:20px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<THIS STYLE WILL CREATE A HOVER EFFECT WITH ROUND CORNER BORDER. HOPE IT SOLVED YOUR ISSUE !>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider an `svg` loaded as a background image with `::before` or `::after` pseudo-classes.

Comment: Very vague answer that could've functioned as a comment. Maybe add an example and more clarity.

Comment: You must change the website url on your profile

Comment: And this is related to the question... how?